# How can I watch the contents of the temp buffer created by `with-temp-buffer` while debugging with edebug?

Tags: edebug

I'm stepping through a function and it calls `with-temp-buffer` and then inserts some stuff. I'm trying to debug the function and I want to see what's in the temp buffer. I tried hitting `e` for `edebug-eval-expression` and running `(switch-to-buffer (current-buffer))` but nothing happens. `(current-buffer)` says `#<buffer  *temp*>`. I just realized that I can call `(buffer-string)` to see the contents. Now I have a different question.

How can I watch the latest value of `(buffer-string)` in the context of the temp buffer? I only see some docs on watching variables but I don't see how I can get what I want. I want to step through edebug with SPC and see the contents at each step.

Not that it matters but [this](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy/blob/fe44efd21573868638ca86fc8313241148fabbe3/lispy.el#L7290C7-L7290C7) is the function that I'm trying to debug.

Comment: I have never used this, so I can't construct an answer out of this, but I think you're looking for "evaluation lists" - https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Eval-List.html

Comment: Ooh, nice! I did not see that. Let me try that out. Thanks!

Comment: if this works, would you mind making an answer with what you did and post it, for future users of the site (including me) ? :)

Comment: I'm not able to get it working.
I tried with this example code
```
(defun watwat ()
  (message
   (with-temp-buffer (insert "How are you?")
                     (beginning-of-buffer)
                     (insert "Hey,\n")
                     (buffer-string))))
```
C-u C-M-x eval-defun to enabled debugging then call it from M-: eval-expression and hit E for edebug-visit-eval-list. That opens another window but idk what to do next. C-h m and read through the bindings. I thought I'd be able to type out `(buffer-string)` and see the result but I can't type in this window. Thanks!